# bash, "\" in an alias or function

Tags: linux, bash, alias, function

I use Windows and Linux a lot, and sometimes I type `cd\` from Windows muscle-memory, so I tried to alias that, `alias cd\='cd /'` but that doesn't work (presumably because `\` is an the escape character in Linux). Is there a way, using an alias or a function that I could make typing `cd\` => `cd /` ?

Comment: Maybe you should just try to avoid typing `cd\ ` ? Seem to be the simplest solution. As the joke goes: *`[client] Doctor, my arm is hurting when I do like this [waving his arm around]. [doc]: So don't do like that!`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be hard, since the backslash is used to escape the next character, and at end of line, it starts a continuation line. So even if you could make a function called `cd\`, you'd need to run it as `cd\\`, or `'cd\'`. And with aliases, escaping or quoting part of the name prevents alias expansion...

Anyway, you can't create those aliases or functions in Bash:

```
$ alias cd\\='echo foo'
bash: alias: `cd\': invalid alias name
$ cd\\ () { echo foo; }
bash: `cd\\': not a valid identifier
```

You can in Zsh, though, but you need the double-backslash...

```
% cd\\ () { echo foo; }
% cd\\ 
foo
```

Actually it even seems to accept the alias, but you can't use it:

```
% alias foo\\='echo bar' 
% foo\\
zsh: command not found: foo\
% 'foo\'
zsh: command not found: foo\
```

Bash can run an external command with a backslash in the name, but that doesn't help with `cd`.